# Best way to find if a string is in a list (without generics)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I want do something like this:

```
Result = 'MyString' in [string1, string2, string3, string4];
```

This can't be used with strings and I don't want to do something like this:

```
Result = (('MyString' = string1) or ('MyString' = string2));
```

Also I think that creating a StringList to do just this is too complex.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could use `AnsiIndexText(const AnsiString AText, const array of string AValues):integer` or `MatchStr(const AText: string; const AValues: array of string): Boolean;` (Both from `StrUtils` unit)

Something like:

```
Result := (AnsiIndexText('Hi',['Hello','Hi','Foo','Bar']) > -1);
```

or

```
Result := MatchStr('Hi', ['foo', 'Bar']);
```

> AnsiIndexText returns the 0-offset
> index of the first string it finds in
> AValues that matches AText
> **case-insensitively**. If the string
> specified by AText does not have a
> (possibly case-insensitive) match in
> AValues, AnsiIndexText returns –1.
> Comparisons are based on the current
> system locale.
>
> MatchStr determines if any of the
> strings in the array AValues match the
> string specified by AText using a **case
> sensitive comparison**. It returns true
> if at least one of the strings in the
> array match, or false if none of the
> strings match.

Note `AnsiIndexText` has case-insensitively and `MatchStr` is  case sensitive so I guess it depends on your use

**EDIT: 2011-09-3**: Just found this answer and thought I would add a note that, in Delphi 2010 there is also a `MatchText` function which is the same as `MatchStr` but case insenstive. -- Larry

Comment: Actually there is a better one, just searched a little in the StrUtils.pas and found the MatchStr which returns a Boolean:
Result := MatchStr('Hi', ['foo', 'Bar']);
Please add it to your answer.

Comment: MatchStr and MatchText are also available in Delphi 2007.

Comment: any equivalent for delphi 7 ?

Comment: @JerryGagnon: In which unit? I can't find them in `SysUtils`

Comment: @Fabrizio they are in `StrUtils`

Answer (score 9):

The code by Burkhard works, but iterates needlessly over the list even if a match is found.

Better approach:

```
function StringInArray(const Value: string; Strings: array of string): Boolean;
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for I := Low(Strings) to High(Strings) do
    if Strings[i] = Value then Exit;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that does the job:

```
function StringInArray(Value: string; Strings: array of string): Boolean;
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := Low(Strings) to High(Strings) do
  Result := Result or (Value = Strings[I]);
end;
```

In fact, you do compare MyString with each string in Strings. As soon as you find one matching you can exit the for loop.

Comment: This works, please update your code with the Delphi one:
  function StringInArray(Value: string; Strings: array of string): Boolean;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    Result := False;
    for I := Low(Strings) to High(Strings) do
      Result := Result or (Value = Strings[I]);
  end;